# How to assign value of xargs command into a variable in bash?

Tags: bash

I need to assign a variable `$x` value that returns from the command `'file'` on `$1`.
my code is:

```
echo $1 | xargs file 'x=$'
```

and the last part `x=$` does not work.
I need that if the argument `$1` is `'archive.zip'` then the variable `x` will get the value of the command `'file'` on it.
How can I do that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could just go with `x=$(file $1)`

Answer (score 2):

Assign value to a variable in shell script is like below

```
  a=$(echo $1 | xargs file)
```

The above means that execute what is inside  `$(...)` and the output will be assigned to a variable with name `a`
Access contents of variable `a`

```
 echo $a
```

You can execute also directly the `file` command with argument the file name and then store the output to a variable.

`$1` is a special argument and its the first argument that used to call a script.

**Example1**:

```
root@server[/root] > echo wiki.20191206.tar.gz | xargs file
wiki.20191206.tar.gz: gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Fri Dec  6 00:00:01 2019
root@server[/root] > a=$(echo wiki.20191206.tar.gz | xargs file)
root@server[/root] > echo $a
wiki.20191206.tar.gz: gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Fri Dec 6 00:00:01 2019
```

**Example2**:

```
root@server[/root] > file wiki.20191206.tar.gz
wiki.20191206.tar.gz: gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Fri Dec  6 00:00:01 2019
root@server[/root] > a=$(file wiki.20191206.tar.gz)
root@server[/root] > echo $a
wiki.20191206.tar.gz: gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Fri Dec 6 00:00:01 201
```

Comment: This question is clearly a duplicate (so is your answer). Next time you encounter such a question, instead of posting an answer, just flag and move on please